# How to generate a summary from a list?

Tags: tcl

I have a list:

```
set aList {aa aa aa bb bb cc cc cc cc aa aa bb cc cc cc cc}
```

I would like to generate a summary that looks something like:

```
3 aa 2 bb 4 cc 2 aa 1 bb 4 cc
```

I am able to generate the summary by using a foreach loop, but am looking for a better solution.

Comment: i am able to generate the summary by using foreach loop, just looking for better solution

Comment: Add the authors question to the actual question and minor cleanup

Comment: Not directly related, but have a look at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Tcl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is basically an RLE encoding command. I don't know of any, but there might be one somewhere -- whether it fits your format is another matter. There is a page called RLE on the wiki, but that's just a user signature.

Otherwise, it's hard to avoid iterating commands when processing an iterative structure. You could try recursion:

```
set aList {aa aa aa bb bb cc cc cc cc aa aa bb cc cc cc cc}

proc summarize {result theList} {
    if {[llength $theList] eq 0} {
        return $result
    } else {
        summarize {*}[count $result $theList 1]
    }
}

proc count {result theList theCount} {
    set theList [lassign $theList theToken]
    if {$theToken eq [lindex $theList 0]} {
        count $result $theList [incr theCount]
    } else {
        list [lappend result $theCount $theToken] $theList
    }
}

summarize [list] $aList
```

Brief commentary: the `summarize` function works with two lists, an even-sized (initially empty) list of counts and tokens (`result`) and a list of unprocessed tokens (`theList`). If `theList` is empty, the `result` list is the result of the operation. If there is at least one token in `theList`, we prepare a new pair of similar lists by counting how many identical tokens we have in the head of `theList`, and summarize those two lists instead. For every application, `result` will be longer by one pair, and `theList` will be shorter by some number of tokens ≥1.

It could be expressed symbolically (with quasi-ML notation) as

summarize (R, Ø) → R
 summarize (R, L) → summarize count (R, L, 1)

The `count` function takes the same two lists, and also a count (initially 1: if `theList` wasn't empty, we will always have at least one token to count). It breaks off one token at the head of `theList` and compares it to the (now shortened) `theList`. If `theToken` is identical to the first token in `theList`, we increment `theCount` and apply `count` again. If it isn't, we extend `result` with `theCount` and `theToken`, having finished counting one kind of token (execution then passes back through the layers of calls back to `summarize`).

Note that calling `count` with an empty list for `theList` will result in an infinite loop: summarize will never call it unless there are tokens in `theList`.

count (R, (T :: (T :: L)), N) → count (R, (T :: L), N+1)
 count (R, (*a* :: L), N) → ((R @ (N :: (*a* :: Ø))), L)

Comment: Sorry for the excessive 'splaining, I have a splitting headache and need to distract myself.

Answer (score 0):

Following function which runs through the list and maintains count of current item works:

```
proc group_identical {slist} {
    set newlist {}
    set current [lindex $slist 0] 
    set count 0
    foreach ele $slist {
        if { ![string compare $ele $current] } {  ;# same as current; 
            incr count
        } else {                ;# new element
            lappend newlist $count $current
            set current $ele
            set count 1
        }
    }
    lappend newlist $count $current
    return $newlist
}

set aList {aa aa aa bb bb cc cc cc cc aa aa bb cc cc cc cc}
puts [group_identical $aList]
```

Output:

```
3 aa 2 bb 4 cc 2 aa 1 bb 4 cc
```